# jquery object don't have attributes property

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I want to enumerate jquerObj.attributes property to get my own data from some tags.
and this works for me almost everywhere:
`$('selector').eq(0);`
It returns a jquery object(only 1) which contains many properties including "attributes", and the property "attributes" can be enumerated.
But when I want to load data from a "table" tag like this:

```
$('#tableId').eq(0);
```

It returns an odd object like an array, it contains property "0","length"(=1),"prevObject".
I've tested in console（obj is the return value of eq(0)）:

```
  obj[0];   // it looks like a DOM object 
    $(obj[0]);  //get obj again.
    obj.attributes===undefined;
    obj.id===undefined;
    obj.attr('id')==='#tableMain';  //THIS IS SO ODD. It looks like it is a jquery object!
```

btw, jquery datatable plugin is loaded.
I don't known how to do next...Thanks!

Comment: What's clearly the case is that `obj` **starts off** as a jQuery object. The `.eq()` method does not return a DOM element. jQuery objects don't have an "attributes" property.

Comment: [**`.eq`**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) return a reduced jQuery object. So it is a jQuery object that has not a `attributes` property.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir  I have tried to read attrs from tag button and table. it works for tag button. why table has no attributes? thankyou!

Comment: @Pointy which kind of obj has attributes? I can get it from other tag (including th)except table. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly normal. You can't call jQuery methods on plain html elements. Consider this:

```
$('any-selector').eq(0).each(function () {
  console.log(this)
  console.log($(this))
})
```

You will get two other objects, as the jQuery adds some magic to each element, it wraps them. So you can do this:

```
$('selector').getAttribute('id') // calling js method on jQuery object
```

But not vice-versa:

```
var elm = document.getElementById('id')
elm.text() // calling jQuery method on plain dom object
// but you can wrap it with jQuery and then call jQuery method
$(elm).text()
```

Comment: I can invoke Some jquery method like attr with the object which is returned by eq(0). I think that means it is a jquery object. why there is no attributes property like other selector? meanwhile, I can use attr to get specified attribute. that means the object contains att info. so I m confur. thanks for ur help again

Comment: Just do not mix jQuery objects with DOM objects and everything will work. And, of course, read attributes appropriate way - with particular methods. Not directly, as with plain objects.

Comment: I've got it now.
The object which containing 'length' ,'0' property is normal jquery object.
The jquery object does not have "attributes" property.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for every one.
I've got it now. The mistake is that I think $('selector') returns an array of jquery object, which is wrong.
I used this to get attributes for others and it succeed.

```
   var objs = $('selector');
    $.each(objs,function(idx,obj){   
          //obj here is a plain html object    
           $.each(obj.attributes,function(a,b){});
    }
```

And used this to get the table tag and it failed.

```
var obj = $('selector').eq(0);    //returns jquery object.
$.each(obj.attributes,function(a,b){});
```

Thanks again!